# Which should I use for mouse over tooltip for image (alt, longdesc, title)

Tags: html, accessibility

Currently, my webpage images use the alt attribute only.
Users complain that their IE8 cannot show the "tooltip" bubble when they mouse over the image. On Microsoft's [What's New in Internet Explorer 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288472.aspx) page, it says

> The alt attribute is no longer displayed as the image tooltip when the
>   browser is running in IE8 Standards mode. Instead, the target of the
>   longDesc attribute is used as the tooltip if present; otherwise, the
>   title is displayed. The alt attribute is still used as the Microsoft
>   Active Accessibility name, and the title attribute is used as the
>   fallback name only if alt is not present.

I also found that many say title should be used.
Which should I use to meet the industrial standard: alt, longdesc or title?

Comment: The `alt` attribute doesn't produce a tooltip in _any_ browser except IE7 and earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many CMSes place that content in both the `title` and the `alt` attributes, but those attributes do have different semantic meanings. Whereas `title` is explicitly meant to be used for tooltips, `alt` is (a) what's read to visually impaired users, and (b) what gets rendered if the image doesn't load for some reason. If you're only going to write one piece of text and duplicate it using jQuery, I would write it for the `alt` attribute and copy it to the `title` using the following jQuery code:

```
$().ready(function(){
    $('img[alt]').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('title', $(this).attr('alt'));
    }
}
```

Be sure to modify the `img[alt]` piece if you don't want to apply this change to every image on the page; for instance, use `#content img[alt]` to only apply it to descendants of `<div id="content">`.

The decision to use `alt` over `title` in your HTML is based on three factors: first, accessibility is important, and you can't rely on Javascript being enabled; second, it sounds like you already have `alt` attributes in place; third, the tooltip in this case is a nonstandard user request you may want to disable in the future, but the images should still have that text associated with them even if you do.

Answer (score 1):

Title attributes in `<img>` tags are what show up on mouse over by default. I would use the title attribute or use a jQuery plugin to create nicer tool tips on mouse hover.

Comment: The _jQuery plugin_ should still be based on the `title` attribute in order to be accessible.

Comment: @w3d what are you talking about? "The jQuery plugin" using title attributes should still be based on the title? This one certainly doesn't http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/ and i'm sure others are similar.

Comment: The `title` attribute is the _accessible_ way to provide a tooltip cross browser. Any enhanced JavaScript tooltip can go way beyond what the meagre `title` attribute can provide but all I'm saying is that this should still be used in conjunction with the `title` attribute in order to be accessible. The jQuery plugin you link to _can_ be used with the `title` attribute and it is only truly [degradable](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/features/#degradable) (listed as one of its features) if the `title` attribute is used.